# How to select child tag by closest tag in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i have select the element in jQuery who used currently clicked. i try parent but that's not worked so i try the closest tag in jQuery

```
$(this).closest('.posts').children('.cbl h1').html('1')
```

i try this and it's work fine to selection means i select the tag .cbl h1  successfully. now tell me how  i can change the text to 1.

structure

```
   <div class='posts'>
    <div class='cbl'>
    </div>
<div><div>$(this) element is here</div></div>
    </div>
```

Comment: If you selected it correctly, then that *is* how you would change the text.

Comment: This question is about changing the text, not selecting child tag by closeness. Please fix the title.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [**`.text()`**](http://api.jquery.com/text/) method.

Something like

```
$(this).closest('.posts').children('.cbl h1').text('1');
```